# Proof $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } \frac{2n+1}{3n+2} = \frac 23$ Using Formal Definition of Limit

Tags: calculus, analysis

I have this question :

Use the definition to prove that

 $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } \frac{2n+1}{3n+2}= \frac{2}{3}$

and this is how approached it, certainly my proof has several flaws in it here we go...

let $\varepsilon > 0$, we then can have $\left | \frac{2n+1}{3n+2}- \frac{2}{3} \right | < \varepsilon$

$\Rightarrow$ $\left | \frac{6n+3-6n-4}{9n+6}\right | = \left| \frac{-1}{9n+6}\right| < \varepsilon$

then we can have

$\left| \frac{-1}{\varepsilon}\right| < 9n+6, \ since\ n>0 \ \forall\ n \in \mathbb{N}$

$\Rightarrow \left | \frac{-1}{9 \varepsilon} -\frac{2}{3}\right | < n $

Now my formal proof goes like this;

$ let\ \varepsilon >0, \exists\ n^* \in \mathbb{N}\ such\ that \left | \frac{2n+1}{3n+2}- \frac{2}{3} \right | < \varepsilon \  \forall \ n \geqslant n^* \ $

$ take\ n^* > \left | \frac{1}{9\varepsilon} \right| $ and we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } \frac{2n+1}{3n+2}= \frac{2}{3} $

Comment: Thank you Stefan4024 for editing the title. I was not sure if I need to put the problem in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things look good, some minor details are discussed below. 
First off, given arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$. You need to show that $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for $n \geqslant N$:
$$
\left|\frac{2n+1}{3n+2}-\frac{2}{3}\right| < \epsilon 
$$
All of your algebra looks correct, you end up getting:
$$
\left|\frac{1}{9n+6}\right| < \epsilon 
$$
Which is equivalent to:
$$
\left|9n+6\right| > \frac{1}{\epsilon}
$$
And notice that this is equivalent with:
$$
9n+6 > \frac{1}{\epsilon}
$$
Since $n$ is nonnegative. Therefore:
$$
n>\frac{1}{9\epsilon}-\frac{2}{3}
$$
So, $N = \lceil\dfrac{1}{9\epsilon}\rceil$ works. I don't know why you've got absolute value signs around the expression with epsilon, you don't need those because $\epsilon >0$.